# how would I turn these functions into a loop?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

So I've created an erb block that iterates through a set of images, and then displays div.tagged for each image at the given coordinates. In this particular case the block iterates through 2 images. What I've created below works perfectly however the content is going to be dynamically added, so I need to figure out a way to loop the values of span.i_contact, .i_tagmap, span.o_contact, and o_tagmap in the jQuery function. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

ERB

```
<% if @new_manual.present? %>
<% n = 0 %>
<% @new_manual.steps.each do |step| %>
    <% n += 1 %>
    <% i_connection = Contact.find(step.input_contact) %>
        <span class="i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>"></span>

    <% o_connection = Contact.find(step.output_contact) %>
        <span class="o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>"> </span>

<br>
<div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
    <%= image_tag(i_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class="i_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
</div>

<div class="image_panel<%= n %>" style="float:left; width:600px; position:relative;">
    <%= image_tag(o_connection.image.image.url(:large)) %>
<div class="o_tagmap<%= n %>"></div>
</div>      

<% end %>   
<% end %>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('span.i_contact1').each(function() {                //needs to be .i_contact(x)
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) + -125;
    console.log(ypos)
    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid red",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos
    });
    $('.i_tagmap1').append(taggedNode)        //needs to be .i_tagmap(x)
});

$("span.o_contact1").each(function() {            //needs to be .o_contact(x)
    var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
    var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
    var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
    var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

    var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
    taggedNode.css({
        "border":"5px solid red",
        "width":pos_width,
        "height":pos_height,
        "left":xpos,
        "top":ypos  
    });
    $('.o_tagmap1').append(taggedNode)        //needs to be .o_tagmap(x)
});
```

**EDIT**

[Link to the generated HTML](https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6059469)

Comment: Can you add a sample of generated html also along with the erb

Comment: Sure. https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6059469

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a minor change to the markup could be needed (Added class `i_contact` and `o_contact` and `data-index`)

```
<span class="i_contact i_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= i_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= i_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= i_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= i_connection.pos_height %>" ="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"></span>

<span class="o_contact o_contact<%= n %>" data-pos-x="<%= o_connection.pos_x %>" data-pos-y="<%= o_connection.pos_y %>"  data-pos-width="<%= o_connection.pos_width %>" data-pos-height="<%= o_connection.pos_height %>" id="spanid<%= n %>" data-index="<%= n %>"> </span>
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('span.i_contact').each(function() {                //needs to be .i_contact(x)
        var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
        var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
        var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
        var ypos = ($(this).data('pos-y')) + -125;
        console.log(ypos)
        var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
        taggedNode.css({
            "border":"5px solid red",
            "width":pos_width,
            "height":pos_height,
            "left":xpos,
            "top":ypos
        });

        var n = $(this).data('index')
        $('.i_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)        //needs to be .i_tagmap(x)
    });

    $("span.o_contact").each(function() {            //needs to be .o_contact(x)
        var pos_width = $(this).data('pos-width');
        var pos_height = $(this).data('pos-height');
        var xpos = $(this).data('pos-x');
        var ypos = $(this).data('pos-y');

        var taggedNode = $('<div class="tagged" />')
        taggedNode.css({
            "border":"5px solid red",
            "width":pos_width,
            "height":pos_height,
            "left":xpos,
            "top":ypos  
        });
        var n = $(this).data('index')
        $('.o_tagmap' + n).append(taggedNode)        //needs to be .o_tagmap(x)
    });
});
```

Comment: @EricFilkins I've updated the gist with another solution https://gist.github.com/filkinsteez/6059469

Comment: @EricFilkins also your html is broken because there are few places where `id` attribute name is missing in `i_contact` element. Also there are duplicate id values for multiple elements

Comment: Hmm interesting, I'll play around with that version as well. Thank you!